# What is the best way to analyze survey responses?

Tags: r, regression, survey

I have survey responses that are between 1 and 10. The questions are related to a category. For example, out of 20 questions, 5 are related to category A, 6 are for category B, and 9 are for category C. How can I analyze this data to determine which category is the most important driver of the overall quality score.

Regression seems like a good initial run but I would think that the categories would be lost in the analysis. FWIW, I am using R for this analysis.